# How do I implement Redux async middleware with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, middleware

I need some help with TS.

I migrate one of my project to TypeSctipt.
The app is on React+Redux stack.

I have my custom fetch middleware which is something like this:

```
import { Action, Dispatch, MiddlewareAPI } from 'redux';

import { TReduxAction } from 'interfaces';

export default ({ dispatch }: MiddlewareAPI) => (next: Dispatch<Action>) => (
  action: TReduxAction
) => {
  const { apiService, ...restActionProps } = action;

  if (apiService === undefined) {
    return next(action);
  }

  dispatch({ ...restActionProps, status: 'PENDING' });

  return apiService(action.body).then(
    (response: Response) => {
      return next({
        type: action.type,
        data: response,
        status: 'SUCCESS',
      });
    },
    (error: Error) =>
      next({
        ...action,
        error,
        status: 'ERROR',
      })
  );
};
```

my action creators are like this

```
const apiService = createApiService();

export function login(body: ILoginRequest) {
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN,
    body,
    apiService: apiService.login,
  };
}
```

and in the app I dispatch it like this

```
dispatch(login(payload));
```

and it works fine. in 80% of cases

But. There is a "but"

sometimes I need to have a response on component level (to show an error or to do something additional)
and in my JS version I simply used `.then()`

```
dispatch(login(payload)).then((res) => { // do stuff });
```

because middleware returns a promise

This is not gonna work with TS.
It says

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type '{ type: string; body: ILoginRequest; apiService: (request: ILoginRequest) => Promise<TLoginResponse | TLoginError>; }'
```

because it doesn't know that the middleware returns a promise.

So how do I type dispatch with async middleware to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with yours. I tried to solve by defining a new `TypedDispatch` and use `createDispatchHook` from `react-redux`

```
export interface TypedDispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> extends Dispatch {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T['apiService'] extends never ? T : Promise<unknown>;
}

export const useDispatch: () => TypedDispatch = createDispatchHook<RootState>();
```

Now just use the `useDispatch` exported instead of `react-redux`'s.